# How to make full translations in Magento?

Tags: magento

I have uploaded the "ro_RO" folder (for roumanian language) in the 'app/locale' folder but some words are still in english. For example, in the create account form, i got the field "email" translated but the "First name" and "Last name" are still in english. The mesages generated by javascript are still in English. What more do I have to do get a full translation? (if I open the .csv files those words appears as translated)

Answer (score 0):

Check the template files for strings output with __(). Those are the exact strings that need to be translated in csv

Comment: There are strings that are outputed with __(), but still some of them don't get translated ( although those strings are translated in the csv files). But what about the javascript translations?